# extract result id and session id from azure congnitive speech

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to extract session id and result id from the azure cognitive services speech package as code below, I tried lot of resources online but no where has mentioned aboout it.

```
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import os
import time

path = os.getcwd()

speech_key, service_region = "", ""
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)

speech_config.speech_recognition_language="en-US"

speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config)

result = ''
done = False 

def stop_cb(evt):
    print('CLOSING on {}'.format(evt))
    speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
    global done
    done= True




def collectResult(evt):
   global result 
   result += evt.result.text

speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(lambda evt: collectResult(evt))

speech_recognizer.session_started.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STARTED: {}'.format(evt)))
speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STOPPED {}'.format(evt)))
speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(lambda evt: print('CANCELED {}'.format(evt)))

speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)
speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(stop_cb)

speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()

while not done:
    print(result)
    time.sleep(.5)
```

output [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bEN1.png)

Answer (score 0):

The two fields you want are the [RecognitionResult.result_id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-speech/azure.cognitiveservices.speech.recognitionresult?view=azure-python) and the [SessionEventArgs.session_id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-speech/azure.cognitiveservices.speech.sessioneventargs?view=azure-python)

So, using the code above, modify the callbacks like so:

```
speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(lambda evt: print('Result ID: {}'.format(evt.result.result_id)))

speech_recognizer.session_started.connect(lambda evt: print('Session ID: {}'.format(evt.session_id)))
```